# Validate email address irrespective of the domain

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How to validate the given email address is correct irrespective of the domain.

for an example if i give

someone@gmail.com

or

someone@yahoo.com

like wise if i give any address the system must be able to say the given address is present at the domain

Comment: There is no way to validate that a given email address is actually valid until you send an email (and possibly get a bounce). You can verify the format of the email address, but not the validity.

Comment: Hi, a warning. You have multiple deleted/closed questions now, and if you get too many of those, in proportion to open questions, the site will automatically prohibit you from posting more questions. This is just a heads-up, but please consult [faq] and [ask] on what is a good question / what is on-topic for this site. Thanks. (if you want to get rid of this comment, just respond to it here and I'll remove them both)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot in general validate that a given address is valid for a domain, short of sending an email and checking for a bounce.

Back in the day some email servers supported that type of query, but spammers promptly abused it so the capability was removed long ago.

You can validate that a domain is a valid one by e.g. doing a DNS lookup and looking for at least one MX record (MX indicates not only that the domain is valid, but that there's a mail exchanger entered in DNS).

It's non-trivial to validate with certainty whether an input string conforms to the format of a valid email address.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) for a detailed discussion.

**UPDATE**

There are a few validators out there in common use that may be helpful, although they do not correctly perform validation in all cases, e.g.

[Apache Commons EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html)
(docs state that it does not catch all cases, including does not check that the top level domain exists).

[RegEx example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx)
My own unit tests indicate that it gives both false negatives and false positives for valid (but certainly uncommon) email addresses.

The [Wikipedia article on email addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax) provides a great overview of valid email address format and provides references to the appropriate RFCs.